# Numerical upper bound of $o(1)$

Tags: number-theory

What can be a numerical upper bound for the $x$ in the following formula ($n \ge 1$):

$$x < ((1 + o(1))n\log n$$

I mean to replace $o(1)$ with some number or constant. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you confused smallOh with BigOh? They mean different things. Not sure what your question is though. Yes, you can replace it with say $x < 2n \log n$, but that is not what the first sentence seems to be asking.

Comment: No confusion. It is smallOh. I want to replace that smallO in upper bound (although smallO is usually for lower bound), with a number

Comment: SmallOh is used for upper bound, not lower bound. What is your definition of SmallOh?

Comment: f(x) is o(g(x)) means that growth of f(x) is nothing compared to g(x). (Correct: it is upper bound) So maximum of $o(1)$ is $1$ so $x<2n\log n$. OK?

Comment: Yes. OK. But you must also say 'for sufficiently large $n$'. btw, maximum of a $o(1)$ function can be anything, even $10^{10^{10}}$. Only for sufficiently large $n$, can you say it is $\lt 1$.

Answer (score 2):

No and yes.

You cannot go from
$$
x<(1+o(1))n\log n
$$
to
$$
x < (1+C)n\log n ~~~ \mathrm{for~all}~n\ge1
$$
since the first bound also includes functions like $x(n) = n\log n + 10C\log n$ which will violate the bound for $n\le 10$.

But you can say that for any $C>0$ there is a number $N(C)$ such that 
$$
x < (1+C)n\log n ~~~ \mathrm{for~all}~n>N(C)
$$
that is, as @Aryabhata said in the comments, "for sufficiently large $n$." (This is the definition of $o(1)$.)

For example if $x(n)=n\log n + 10\log n$ then $x<2n\log n$ for all $n>10$, and $x<1.001n\log n$ for all $n>10^4$.